# dividing two fields from two different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In an MS Access 2010 database, I have two tables which each have a common key.  I want to divide the value of a field in one of the tables by the value of a different field in another table.  How do I accomplish this in MS Access SQL code?

I want to do this in SQL.  There is no graphical user interface.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT result AS (tblone.DAYS / tbltwo.DIS) 
FROM tblone INNER JOIN tbltwo
ON tblone.NO = tbltwo.NO;
```

NOTE: the `DAYS` and `DIS` fields are both of data type `Double`.  `NO` is a `Long Integer` in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND((tblone.DAYS / tbltwo.DIS), 2) AS result 
FROM tblone INNER JOIN tbltwo
ON tblone.NO = tbltwo.NO;
```

Read here to learn more about the <kbd>[`ROUND()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/round.php)</kbd>  Function.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for answering my question.  It won't let me accept your answer for another 10 mins or so.  Can you also show me how to round the answer to a specified number of decimal places?

Comment: Don't forget the where clause to prevent division by 0.

Comment: @DanBracuk How do I specify tbltwo.DIS!=0

Comment: Use a WHERE clause something like `WHERE tbltwo.DIS <> 0`